# Detail band longer than necessary in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, pdf-generation, ireport

I have a detail band with text fields and a table. In the designer view I have fit all the band, but when I see the preview the lowest text field is higher than the first text field in the next band (i.e. I have empty space between band 1 and band 2).

The empty space is due by the table, in fact if I remove it I have no empty space. Below the designer view and preview.

[image: Designer view]

[image: Preview]

The question is: how I can avoid the empty space between the bands? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT2**: Now that the report is shown, it's clear. Make the table bigger in the report layout. Stretch it all the way to the bottom. When you don't, JR is careful to include as much space below it as you have left there.

**EDIT**: I think the key issue is that the band height should be "20" to match the height of the elements in it.

**Old answer containing trivia that might or might not matter**:
Some of your "text fields" are `textField`s. This is good. Some of your "text fields" are `staticText`. This is bad. Convert the static text to real text fields. You can right-click them and automatically transform them.

stretchType is bad. Turn that off. (Actually, it's good and useful... but it's not what you want.)

isStretchWithOverflow is good. Turn it on. Your text says that it's already on, but your code shows that it is not.

isPrintWhenDetailOverflows is bad. Turn it off. Your text makes no mention of it, but your code shows that it is on. (It's probably irrelevant... but you should turn it off to be clear that it's not what you think it is.)

Comment: Ok. I've converted all staticText in textField, stretchType is off, isStretchWithOverflow is on (in the question I confused it with isPrintWhenDetailOverflows), finally isPrintWhenDetailOverflows is on (text will may overflow the band in some case, but not in my example). The problem is the same, see my edit question.

Comment: The height of the band is 140 because I have a lot of these fields, but this is the minimum height in order to fit all the fields. If I set the band height to a value less than 120 some fields color themselves in red (warning) and if I try to see the preview I see this message: element bottom reaches outside band area...

Comment: Then I think we don't have enough info to know what's going on. But you might just need to set the height of all of the fields to be 120.

Comment: I have edited my question because I've understood that the problem is a table in the band and not the text fields, sorry.